# How to keep parameters unchanged in recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, quicksort

I am trying to implement Quick Sort algorithm, here's my code:

```
public class Sort {

int count = 0;

public void Partition(int A[], int l, int h) {

    if ((h-l) > 1) {

    count += (h-l) - 1;    

        int pivot = A[l];
        int i = l+1;
        int temp;
        int j;

        for (j = l + 1; j < h; j++) {

            if (A[j] < pivot) {  // SWAP
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
                i++;
            }
            // else : j++            
        }

        temp = A[i-1];   
        A[i-1] = A[l];
        A[l] = temp;

        Partition(A, l, i-1);               
        Partition(A, i, A.length);

    }
  }
}
```

the code does sort the input array, but when i count the number of comparisons, it gives a number, much greater than the original number of the comparisons. I added a break point and moved a step by step into the code, and found that the problem lies in the last two lines: 
Partition(A, l, i-1);
Partition(A,i, A,length);

The 'i' sent in the 2nd call, is the i resulting from the 1st call to the function Partition, and not the 'i' from the very first code. for example, the first time the code runs on the following input: 
3 8 4 6 10 2 5 7 1
the output is: 1 2 3 4 6 10 9 5 7 8
and i = 3.
then the first call to Partition takes i (where i equals 3) and keeps changing the i's value, when it's finally done, the i's value is different than 3, and another wrong value is sent to the 2nd recursive call.

My question is, is there a way, so that the two calls take the same parameter i, without anyone changing it ?

Comment: There is no way the first call can change the value of the parameter `i`. You must be mistaken.

Comment: That's what I thought, I mean that's what I understand about recursion, but when moved into it step by step, I found that when the code is entering the second call, the i's value is 1, and not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Don't try to do the sort in `Partition`; from there, just return the index `i` (you have to change the return type to int, of course). Then write a different method to implement your quicksort.

```
public static void quicksort(int[] n, int left, int right){
if (left<right){
int pivotindex=Partition(n, left, right);
quicksort(n, left, pivotindex-1);
quicksort(n, pivotindex+1, right);}
}
```

I tested this with the following, and it worked perfectly.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int[] n= new int[8];
n[0]=3;
n[6]=2;
n[1]=5;
n[3]=20;
quicksort(n, 0, n.length);
for (int i=0; i<n.length; i++){
    System.out.print(n[i]+",");
}
}
```

Comment: it did work :D 
only you have to change the second call to quicksort to be in this format so that the output is correct:
quicksort(n, pivotindex, right);
also I had to remove the static declaration from the quicksort class, cause otherwise the int pivotindex showed an error.

I wonder how did this fix the problem ? 
I tried doing something similar before and it didn't work, however this worked just fine :)
Thank you :)

Comment: Could you explain why did this work, while the original posted code didn't ?

Comment: I was analyzing what was wrong with your code and I might have found a simpler solution to your problem. Try changing the second recursive call to `Partition(A, i+1, A.length)` and see what happens. I tried this, and got the correct number of comparisons. The problem seems to be not that `i` is changing for the second call, but that it _isn't_ changing...the call is being made to the same subarray over and over.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you had to change `pivotindex+1` to `pivotindex` in the second recursive call in `quicksort`. Could you tell me what the problem was?

Comment: since the **i** returned from the **partition** method is index to the first element after the **pivot**, and not the **pivot** itself, therefore it still needs to be sorted; that's why we start at **pivotindex** and not **pivotindex+1**.  However I wonder how did you get the right number of comparisons while using **pivotindex+1**?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Java` uses *pass-by-value*, there is no way the first call can change the value of the parameter `i`, since the called method has no reference to it.
You are probably expecting the second call to `Partition` to be the next one. However, the first call will in turn call `Partition` twice more, causing the parameter values of the next execution of `Partition` to be different than you might expect.

Also, please start your method names with a lower-case letter.

Comment: alright, maybe the cause of the problem isn't correct, but can you tell me where the problem is ?

the number of comparisons should be 25, while it's giving me 62 !

Comment: Ok sorry about the upper-case :)

I understand that the Partition will call itself couple of times before the 2nd call actually takes place, but what do you mean by
"causing the parameter values of the next execution of Partition to be different than you might expect. "

does this mean that the 'i' does change ??

I mean it's not sent to the 2nd call as 3, the resulted value from the code, but it's now the resulted value after calling the Partition couple of times ??

Comment: No, the value of `i` in that particular method call never changes, but since you get so many calls it is easy to lose track of which execution you are watching when debugging. I'm sorry, I don't even know what you mean by number of comparisons, or how you calculate it, so I can't help you there.

Comment: No problem thanks for your help :)
in case you're interested, number of comparisons is the number of elements the pivot gets compared to each time the function is called.
As for the debugging, I don't know, but I think I get it right, I mean while debugging, the function keeps calling itself, until the highlight moves to the following one, this is when I check the i's value and it's different !! I don't know how.
thanks again.